# How to call scala from python?

Tags: python, scala

I would like to build my project in Scala and then use it in a script in Python for my data hacking (as a module or something like that). I have seen that there are ways to integrate python code into JVM languages with Jython (only Python 2 projects though). What I want to do is the other way around though. I found no information on the net how to do this, but it seems strange that this should not be possible.

Comment: If need be, you can always put a small Java wrapper around any Scala code and use one of the tools for calling Java code from Python. Something like this: https://www.py4j.org/index.html. I haven't used this library. Perhaps it will work directly with Scala without needing to write any Java at all.

Comment: You didn't search hard enough : http://chariotsolutions.com/presentation/polyglot-programming-with-python-pythonscala-interop/

Comment: Why don't you just call a `subprocess`?

Comment: May be have a backend process running in Scala. The scala process and python one can communicate via i/o stream or rpc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General solution -- use some RPC/IPC (sockets, protobuf, whatever).

However, you might want to look at Spark's solution -- how they translate Python code in Scala's APIs (https://www.py4j.org/) .

Answer (score 3):

Recently, [scalapy](https://github.com/shadaj/scalapy) was created to call Python libraries from Scala.

https://github.com/shadaj/scalapy